How to create an AutoHotKey v2 hotstring with a backslash in the trigger
This hotstring in my ahk file doesn't work:
::1\2::½

Other hotstrings work, but not this one. I assumed the problem was that backslash is a hotstring EndCharacter so I tried also doing:
#Hotstring EndChars -()[]{}:;'"/,.?!`n`s`t

But that makes no difference.
How can I get this hotstring to work?

It works for me as-written but you can try to escape the backslash to tell AHK you mean a literal backslash and not some control character.
`::1\`\2::½`

Documentation: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/misc/EscapeChar.htm

It works for me too, are you pressing e.g. spacebar after it, to end the hotstring? What version of AHK exactly?

Since it works for you both, I must have some other problem. So now I realise that I'm using “\” in my hotstring but my “\” is itself hotkeyed from from a different key (I'm on a Mac keyboard but a windows machine). So I should probably close this question and websearch again for that problem, or else I'd be completely changing this question

https://superuser.com/questions/1846156/autohotkey-2-using-inputlevel-for-a-hotkey-in-a-hotstring-not-working
